# PHP Code Style in .htm File in PhpStorm

Tags: php, html, phpstorm, octobercms

If I add some php code to a `.html` or `.htm` file in PhpStorm, the code style for that bit of php code is NOT the same as in `.php` file.

For instance, here is the same code in two different file formats:

**.php**
[image]

**.htm**
[image]

How can I get the php code segment inside of the `.htm` to look like it does in a `.php` file?

**UPDATE**

The reason I want php code styling within an htm file is because I am using [October CMS](http://octobercms.com).  October CMS [uses a .htm file extension](https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/pages#introduction) which is divided into three section.  One of those section [is for php code](https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/themes#php-section).  What I want to know is how can I get the php content code which resides in the htm file to use my php code styles within PhpStorm.

Comment: Please show your source code not the image.

Comment: One files has the `.php` extension and one has the `.htm` extension. PHP  wouldn't work in a `.htm` extension file anyway, so there's no reason for storm to apply php style to it.

Comment: .htm is not supported to interpret PHP syntaxes

Comment: @NikhilVaghla I need to show the images so that you can see the difference in the code styling.  It's not help with the code that I need, but rather help with the code styling within PhpStorm.

Comment: @Andrew Please see my update to the question to understand why I need php code within an htm file (and why it will work).

Comment: @Robin Please see my update to the question to understand why I need php code within an htm file (and why it will work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In order for PhpStorm to recognize and highlight PHP code in any file such file MUST be associated with "PHP File" file type and have PHP icon next to file name.**

By default `.htm`/`.html` files are associated with "HTML Files" file type.

---

Few possible solutions:

1. Change extension of existing file to be `.php`
2. Use `.phtml` file extension -- which is commonly used extension for such cases (in general denotes that this file is a "template" -- a HTML file mixed with PHP instructions)
3. Associate `.htm` (or whatever else extension you want) with "PHP File" file type.

   For that: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types` -- find "PHP File" and add appropriate pattern (e.g. `*.htm`). IDE will ask if you want to remove such pattern from existing/default "HTML File" to this "PHP File".

   Possible downside: some HTML inspections may not be triggered (relaxed) in PHP file.

   **NOTE:** Such association is IDE-wide and affects ALL projects.

---

**The best/most neutral solution overall** is #2 -- use dedicated file extension for such files (`*.phtml` is a most commonly used).

Comment: Thanks, solution #3 is what works for me in this situation as I have to use a .htm file extension (as I explained in the update to my question).

Comment: The only downside is that you cannot then associate .htm file also to Twig, and Twig's syntax highlight and autocompletition don't work. I think the only way is to create a new language, like these [Atom's](https://atom.io/packages/language-octobercms) or [VSC](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dqsully.octobercms-template-language) plugin do

Answer (score 0):

PHP needs to be in a `.php` file. It's changing colour because your text editor is telling you that the browser will treat it as text if it's in a `.html` file.

Rename it to `.php` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Please see my update to the question to understand why I need php code within an htm file.  What I need to know is if there is a way to get PhpStorm to recognize my php code within a htm file.